# How do you add event notifications for my application

Tags: box-api

The [Event Notifications Wiki Page](http://developers.box.net/w/page/51897545/Event%20Notifications) tells you to click edit your app and then shows a screenshot and tells you to click "create new event notification" under the Event Notifications heading.

When I look at the Event Notifications heading for my app it just says "No event notification added" and does not have a clickable link "create new event notification" as shown in the screenshot on the wiki page.

How do I go about adding event notifications when that link is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Event Notifications are currently in beta and need to be manually enabled for your Box API key by someone on our team. Please shoot us an email at API[at]boxDOTcom with your use case, and we'll see if we can get you into the beta.